# how to link c++ program with HTML page?

Tags: c++, html, c

i am working on php...!!
Is it possible to link HTML page to c++/c at back end.
means instead of php script i want to run c/c++
if Yes How??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) and [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastcgi) technologies.

Answer (score 5):

CGI is your best bet if the C++ program is an executable. If you want to use a C++ library from PHP you will need to write an extension. An example of this can be found at http://devzone.zend.com/article/4486

Answer (score 4):

What you are after is [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_gateway_interface).

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the book Extending and Embedding PHP by Sara Goleman [link](http://books.google.com/books?id=zMbGvK17_tYC&dq=extending+and+embedding+php&printsec=frontcover&source=bn&hl=en&ei=FSr8SqrIGseEnQfjkpGWBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CBQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=&f=false)

It is probably the best resource I have found on linking C++ libraries / routines to user space PHP functions.